# I now get an access violation since rebuilding my program using VS2017 with latest toolset - when shutting program down

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017

I have just encountered an issue that I don't know how to resolve. I have a MDI application that I started back in 2002 and it has been ongoing since then.

I went to rebuild it for the first time in VS2017 (using latest toolset) and it all seemed fine apart from when I went to shut down the program. An exception was raised and it took me to the VS2017 IDE:

[image: Exception]

It is really confusing. The stack trace:

```
>   [Inline Frame] CommunityTalks_x64.exe!ATL::CImage::CInitGDIPlus::ReleaseGDIPlus() Line 583  C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] CommunityTalks_x64.exe!ATL::CImage::CInitGDIPlus::{dtor}() Line 555  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!`ATL::CImage::GetInitGDIPlusInstance'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'gdiPlus''()  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!_execute_onexit_table::__l2::<lambda>() Line 206 C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!__crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),int <lambda>(void) & __ptr64,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, _execute_onexit_table::__l2::int <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 204  C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] CommunityTalks_x64.exe!__acrt_lock_and_call(const __acrt_lock_id) Line 936   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!_execute_onexit_table(_onexit_table_t * table) Line 231  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!common_exit::__l2::<lambda>() Line 230   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<void <lambda>(void),void <lambda>(void) & __ptr64,void <lambda>(void) >(__acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && setup, common_exit::__l2::void <lambda>(void) & action, __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::void <lambda>(void) && cleanup) Line 224 C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] CommunityTalks_x64.exe!__acrt_lock_and_call(const __acrt_lock_id) Line 936   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!common_exit(const int return_code, const _crt_exit_cleanup_mode cleanup_mode, const _crt_exit_return_mode return_mode) Line 278  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 290    C++ Symbols loaded.
    kernel32.dll!00007ffcd5301fe4() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!00007ffcd71defb1()    Unknown No symbols loaded.
```

The code that it triggered:

```
inline void CImage::CInitGDIPlus::ReleaseGDIPlus() throw()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_sect);
    if( m_dwToken != 0 )
    {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown( m_dwToken );
    }
    m_dwToken = 0;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_sect);
}
```

This is not my personal code and I don't know what is going on. My output log:

```
The thread 0x2c50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CommunityTalks_x64.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'
'CommunityTalks_x64.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d10warp.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD35E3FB8 (KernelBase.dll) in CommunityTalks_x64.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.
The thread 0x960 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xd84 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1270 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x33c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2308 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x53c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x20c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD71BBE6B (ntdll.dll) in CommunityTalks_x64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024.

The program '[2204] CommunityTalks_x64.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I don't know what is going on and I have to stop the debugging process.

I am in way deep here and I don't know what to do.

## Update

I stumbled over this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/173633/mfc-library-big-bug.html

## Update 2

I tried to place a breakpoint as per the advice in the comments but the exception is already triggered. I was directed to a related issue here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169288/vc2017-1552-mfc-library-big-bug.html

One of the solutions stated:

> As workaround, please try to disable threadSafeInit: add /Zc:threadSafeInit- C++ compiler option) - it should solve the problem.

I have just changed the setting and now the exception does not happen. I also looked up [/Zc:threadSafeInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization) but it is all over my head. All I know is that i did not have an issue before. Unless I add this switch the dbeugger always causes an exception.

How important is this? Is it OK to just follow this work-around?

## Update 3

I switched off WindowsBlinds just incase it was intefering and did a debug trace with breakpoint inside this method:

```
inline bool CImage::CInitGDIPlus::Init() throw()
```

Interestingly this gets intercepted and on closer inspection here is the stack:

```
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!ATL::CImage::CInitGDIPlus::Init() Line 573   C++ Symbols loaded.
    [Inline Frame] CommunityTalks_x64.exe!ATL::CImage::InitGDIPlus() Line 2075  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!ATL::CImage::Load(IStream * pStream) Line 1376   C++ Symbols loaded.
>   CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CPngImage::LoadFromBuffer(unsigned char * lpBuffer, unsigned int uiSize) Line 4057   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CPngImage::Load(const wchar_t * lpszResourceName, HINSTANCE__ * hinstRes) Line 3986  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCToolBarImages::LoadStr(const wchar_t * lpszResourceName, HINSTANCE__ * hinstRes, int bAdd) Line 942  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::LoadImageW(const CMFCRibbonInfo::XID & id, CMFCToolBarImages & image, int bSingle) Line 150    C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::LoadImageW(CMFCRibbonInfo::XImage & image, int bSingle) Line 199   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::LoadFromBuffer(unsigned char * lpBuffer, unsigned int nSize) Line 124  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCRibbonInfoLoader::Load(const wchar_t * lpszResID, const wchar_t * lpszResType, HINSTANCE__ * hInstance) Line 88  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromResource(const wchar_t * lpszXMLResID, const wchar_t * lpszResType, HINSTANCE__ * hInstance) Line 1146    C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CMainFrame::OnCreate(tagCREATESTRUCTW * lpCreateStruct) Line 298 C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam, __int64 * pResult) Line 2292   C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 2099    C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 265  C++ Symbols loaded.
    CommunityTalks_x64.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned __int64 wParam, __int64 lParam) Line 417   C+

+   Symbols loaded.
```

The `CMFCToolBarImages::LoadStr` method has this bit of code:

```
// Try to load PNG image first:
CPngImage pngImage;
if (pngImage.Load(lpszResourceName, hinstRes))
{
    hbmp = (HBITMAP) pngImage.Detach();
}
else
```

This code `if (pngImage.Load(lpszResourceName, hinstRes))` calls:

```
BOOL bRes = LoadFromBuffer((LPBYTE) lpBuffer, (UINT) ::SizeofResource(hinstRes, hRsrc));
```

That `LoadFromBuffer` call is made up like this:

```
BOOL CPngImage::LoadFromBuffer(LPBYTE lpBuffer, UINT uiSize)
{
    ASSERT(lpBuffer != NULL);

    HGLOBAL hRes = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, uiSize);
    if (hRes == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    IStream* pStream = NULL;
    LPVOID lpResBuffer = ::GlobalLock(hRes);
    ASSERT (lpResBuffer != NULL);

    memcpy(lpResBuffer, lpBuffer, uiSize);

    HRESULT hResult = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hRes, TRUE, &pStream);

    if (hResult != S_OK)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (CMFCToolBarImages::m_bMultiThreaded)
    {
        CMFCToolBarImages::m_CriticalSection.Lock();
    }

    if (m_pImage == NULL)
    {
        m_pImage = new CImage;
        ENSURE(m_pImage != NULL);
    }

    m_pImage->Load(pStream);
    pStream->Release();

    BOOL bRes = Attach(m_pImage->Detach());

    if (CMFCToolBarImages::m_bMultiThreaded)
    {
        CMFCToolBarImages::m_CriticalSection.Unlock();
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

Notice it has this code:

```
if (m_pImage == NULL)
{
    m_pImage = new CImage;
    ENSURE(m_pImage != NULL);
}
```

So there we have a `CImage` object. Sure enough:

```
// Attributes:
protected:
    static ATL::CImage* m_pImage;
```

It is all part of the `CPNGImage` class which is used by the  `CMFCToolBarImages` framework and not something that I am doing myself. Without the `threadSafeInit-` flag being added the debugger will always crash for me when the application shuts down.

Comment: That looks like a double-delete bug. Apparently, the `CImage::CInitGDIPlus` destructor runs twice. Try setting a breakpoint on `CImage::CInitGDIPlus::~CInitGDIPlus` before shutdown to find out, where it is called from. That should get you closer to isolating the issue, ideally providing enough information to construct a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable Please see updated question. Thanks.

Comment: I believe *threadSafeInit* implements a feature introduced in C++11, commonly termed [magic statics](http://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/c-plus-plus/magic-statics). Apparently, this not only has an effect on construction of function-local statics, but also on (the order of) destruction. It was introduced with Visual Studio 2015, and is *on* by default. If you are porting code from pre-VS2015, disabling the option is the same as compiling it with a pre-VS2015 compiler. If the code was correct before, it still is without the *threadSafeInit* option enabled.

Comment: I'd still love to see a [mcve] reproducing this issue, to understand, what really is going on. Apparently, the `CImage` implementation does use function-local statics for GDI+ initialization/uninitialization, so this could indeed be a bug in MFC. To safely determine this, the issue would have to be isolated. Although it does sound a bit unreasonable for a commonly used class like `CImage` to have a defect.

Comment: At the moment I can't give you a minimal example because I don't even use the `CImage` class. For now I am just switching the feature off for the project.

Comment: I only use `CBitmap` objects. Not `CImage`.

Comment: That's odd, though. The callstack clearly indicates use of `CInitGDIPlus`, a private nested class of `CImage`, so *someone* must be using `CImage`. My guess would be the `CImageList` class, used by toolbars. Or maybe menus with icons. At any rate, I wasn't necessarily asking you to produce a [mcve]. If I find the time, I'll see if I can put something together. One question, though: Are you linking against the MFC library that comes with Visual Studio 2017, or a previous version, from a previous incarnation of the application?

Comment: Ah, now I *do* use several `CImageList` objects in the application. I am using the 2017 v141 Platform Toolset. And MFC is static linked library.

Comment: CImageList doesn't matter. The problem is the use of GDI+! So the question is: What in you projects uses GDI+ when there is code that tries to uninit it?

Comment: @xMRi according to https://mobile.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/graphics/article.php/c15585/Working-with-Device-Contexts-in-MFC.htm CBitmap is a GDI class. I will investigate.

Comment: I know about CBitmap. As IInspectable wrote, the question is who inits GDI+ and who tries to uninit it again... As I see this reported "big MFC bug", it seams for me a problem about the initialization sequence of global variables... and why the option threadsafeinit fixes the problem? I don't know. But it also may change the sequence of initialization of global variables.

Comment: @xMRi see updated question.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/173633/mfc-library-big-bug.html

Comment: Thanks for the work! Just got bitten hard by this problem, and you made my day! I can confirm `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` solves the problem

Comment: Another big thanks for your work and the /Zc:threadSafeInit- is also working for me here.  In my case it was porting a MFC ribbon based application from VS2015 to VS2017.  I've also added a post to the MS question you previously linked, as they think this issue has been fixed in the latest update, but I don't believe it has.  See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/173633/mfc-library-big-bug.html

Comment: Word of warning on '/Zc:threadSafeInit- I had a very difficult to track down bug on a client site today in Slovenia where my app failed to start.  Checking the dump log located the problem in xlocale.cc happening during startup.  Removing /Zc:threadSafeInit- solved it which suggests to me this switch causes problems with the current VS2017 C++ run-times.  CImage issue seems to be fixed, so removing this switch myself.